# Migrate SVN to Git, lost all source files and most commits

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm trying to migrate a SVN repo to git. I followed https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/03/moving-from-svn-to-git/ and http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git step by step, `git svn clone` generates the following output:

```
$ git svn clone https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ --authors-file=users.txt --no-metadata --stdlayout graph_db > svn2git.log
Using higher level of URL: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ada-main => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/branches/old-hbase-partition-schema, 283
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/old-hbase-partition-schema@283
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/old-hbase-partition-schema) 66e38e56be14a4082c2e30e87319d0f462df022a
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ada-main => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/branches/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, 958
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT@958
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT) f7f94b8d4068df96b5113d39bd7a5cca9585785c


Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ada-main => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/tags/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, 959
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/tags/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT@959
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/tags/ada-main-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT) f7f94b8d4068df96b5113d39bd7a5cca9585785c
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ada-main => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/branches/ada-main-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, 1083
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/ada-main-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@1083
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/ada-main-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) dfa9243061f01064f81d768b22abbf2f34ed8e6e
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/weibo-forecast => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/tags/weibo-forecast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, 1369
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/tags/weibo-forecast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT@1369
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 101, path '/system/graph_db/weibo-forecast'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/tags/weibo-forecast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) 456ece0aa3d789a052568620a85e88f953519533
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/ada-main => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/tags/ada-main-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT, 1459
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/tags/ada-main-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT@1459
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/tags/ada-main-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT) a55432828a6f6d021c4f02e9c267af6a43370e8e
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Found possible branch point: https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/weibo-forecast => https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/tags/weibo-forecast-30min, 1464
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/tags/weibo-forecast-30min@1464
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/tags/weibo-forecast-30min) d89188fb190bb3b822ecdf7b8c96d78b4e1ebb72
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
Checked out HEAD:
  https://zuoyao@10.61.0.242/adasvn/system/graph_db/trunk r961
```

I redirected stdout to `svn2git.log`, **The revision info in this file seems to be correct, as it contains 1000+ revision records**.

Then I entered `graph_db` directory and type `git log`, all I see is three commits

```
commit 99e77af4eeaab9939ecac7ff287984772cf106bf
Author: wangqianbo <wangqianbo@software.ict.ac.cn>
Date:   Tue Dec 10 03:42:44 2013 +0000

commit 214032b4d80772a2ae20f350f2658503faa02233
Author: ada <ada_gitlab@163.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 09:55:26 2013 +0000

    delete test.

commit e26fcdadbb37ee8f98932d15098b80e60ed1a144
Author: ada <ada_gitlab@163.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 25 09:54:45 2013 +0000

    commit test.

commit 7cb9bd0546117d0348b4c40953bf6a1f7ef7cbb7
Author: ada <ada_gitlab@163.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 23 08:13:05 2013 +0000
```

And there's no source file in graph_db, not a single one! I don't know what happened. This is driving me crazy.

**EDIT:**
I gave up. Will migrate without history.

Comment: Run `git branch`. Maybe there are other branches with your code? Run `git checkout branchname` with every branch name that you find this way.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're on `master` branch and you need to switch to `trunk`.

Use `git branch` to get a list of all your branches. Use `git checkout <branch>` to switch.

Use `git log --graph --format=oneline --all --decorate` to see a nicely-formatted log of all commits to give you some more orientation. Or, even better, use a GUI tool.

Comment: I know little about SVN. I'll try it.

Comment: I ran some command to clean svn branches/tags, still doesn't work. There are many remote branches, but only one local branch `master`.

Comment: Ok then, you can checkout one of these using `git checkout` as well.

Comment: I know, but still I got only 3 commits.